# Nuxt server middleware post request not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nuxt.js

I saw in the documentation of Nuxt js (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/) that I can extend server middleware with express.
i tested it with GET request and it worked but when i use POST request there is no body in request.

/api/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import Cities from './offline/cities';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/findCity', function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body.input) {
    res.status(400).json();
    return;
  }
  res.status(200).json(Cities.filter(req.body.input, req.body.opt));
});

module.exports = { path: '/api', handler: app };
```

/nuxt.config.js:

```
serverMiddleware: [ '~/api/index.js' ],
```

mixin.js

```
async findCity(input, opt) {
   return (await this.$axios.post(process.env.DOMAIN_URL + '/api/findCity', { input, opt })).data;
}
```

in chrome dev tools the body is sent:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Exclude body-parser

I don't know if this would directly solve the original problem, but it is an efficiency. This helped me when troubleshooting getting `req.body`.

With Express +4.16, you don't need a separate import for `body-parser` because `.json` and `.urlencoded` are included in Express base.

**Changelog:**
https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.16.0

**An article about it:**
https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c

**This works for me:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())

app.all('/myAPIroute*', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Req body is: ", req.body)
})

module.exports = app
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `/api/index.js` file you can get request data by this way:

```
req.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString())
})
```

Using only `data` you get a readable Buffer object. Adding `.toString()` you have a 'plain text' representation of data.